# Help identify this tool/bit

Tags: tools

This was found in a collection of miscellaneous tools at work.  Similar to a bolt extractor or "easy out", but the threads are way too fine and right-handed.

- Approx. 2.75" overall length.
- Hex end is 7/8".
- Approx. 24 threads per inch.
- Threads are clockwise/right hand.

Take a close look at the threads; it's hard to make out but they're serrated/angled (*for lack of a better term*) towards the narrow end.

Thoughts? :)

[image]

Comment: it looks like a wedge for forcibly separating two parts or for splitting something ... possibly a tool to free a stuck axe

Comment: That's exactly what it is, my grandfather gave me one and showed me how to use it. If your axe or splitting maul gets stuck in a log (especially if it's green), you drive this in a little bit along the same axis, then attach a socket wrench to it to screw it into the wood. It spreads the wood and either splits it altogether, or at least spreads it out enough to get your other tool out. You can use it as a splitter too, it just takes a lot longer. But at the end of the day when I can't lift the axe or maul any more, I sometimes resort to this to finish the pile.